# SQL Server. Separate XML file with FOR XML PATH(...) into a single XML file

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, for-xml-path

I've been reading this article: 
https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/manipulating-xml-data-in-sql-server/

I found what I need, but the only difference in my situation I need to use `FOR XML PATH(...)` **and not** `ROOT(...)` instead of `AUTO` mode.

I have a XML file that uses columns of the table as a elements. The question that I'm trying to resolve:

1) how to produce a single XML file per each record in the select statement;

2) save each xml file with a unique name based on rowId on a shared server

**Note**: hardcoding values for each XML row is not an option as my output contains thousands of rows.

The problem here is that FOR XML and XML data type are not allowed in the Cursor statement.

```
CREATE TABLE #T1 
(
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    LName NVARCHAR(30) NULL,
    FName NVARCHAR(30) NULL,
    Comments NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL
);

GO

INSERT INTO #T1 (ID, LName, FName, Comments)
    VALUES
        (1, 'JONOTHAN', 'SMITH', 'is the best friend ever'),
        (2, 'ROGER', 'SHU`LTS', 'is the boss!'),
        (3, 'Jeremy', 'Deimer', 'is the a good drama actor'),
        (4, 'Alexandra', 'Norusis', 'is the smart feminist');

GO

SELECT 
    t.ID, 
    t.LName, 
    t.FName, 
    t.Comments
FROM #T1 t
    FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT ('body');
```

**Below is the current output of the XML file format:**

```
 <body>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <LName>JONOTHAN</LName>
  <FName>SMITH</FName>
  <Comments>is the best friend ever</Comments>
  <ID>2</ID>
  <LName>ROGER</LName>
  <FName>SHU`LTS</FName>
  <Comments>is the boss!</Comments>
  <ID>3</ID>
  <LName>Jeremy</LName>
  <FName>Deimer</FName>
  <Comments>is the a good drama actor</Comments>
  <ID>4</ID>
  <LName>Alexandra</LName>
  <FName>Norusis</FName>
  <Comments>is the smart feminist</Comments>
</body>
```

**Below is the desired out (based on a record with ID = 1)**

```
        <body>
          <ID>1</ID>
          <LName>JONOTHAN</LName>
          <FName>SMITH</FName>
          <Comments>is the best friend ever</Comments>
        <body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's this what you need:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE 
(
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    LName NVARCHAR(30) NULL,
    FName NVARCHAR(30) NULL,
    Comments NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL
);

INSERT INTO @tbl (ID, LName, FName, Comments)
    VALUES
        (1, 'JONOTHAN', 'SMITH', 'is the best friend ever'),
        (2, 'ROGER', 'SHU`LTS', 'is the boss!'),
        (3, 'Jeremy', 'Deimer', 'is the a good drama actor'),
        (4, 'Alexandra', 'Norusis', 'is the smart feminist');
```

--use this for your `CURSOR`

```
SELECT ID
     ,(SELECT t1.* FOR XML PATH('body'),TYPE) AS TheRowAsXml
FROM @tbl AS t1
```

The result

```
ID  TheRowAsXml
1   <body><ID>1</ID><LName>JONOTHAN</LName><FName>SMITH</FName><Comments>is the best friend ever</Comments></body>
2   <body><ID>2</ID><LName>ROGER</LName><FName>SHU`LTS</FName><Comments>is the boss!</Comments></body>
3   <body><ID>3</ID><LName>Jeremy</LName><FName>Deimer</FName><Comments>is the a good drama actor</Comments></body>
4   <body><ID>4</ID><LName>Alexandra</LName><FName>Norusis</FName><Comments>is the smart feminist</Comments></body>
```

### UPDATE Your example using a CURSOR

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE 
(
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    LName NVARCHAR(30) NULL,
    FName NVARCHAR(30) NULL,
    Comments NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL
);

INSERT INTO @tbl (ID, LName, FName, Comments)
    VALUES
        (1, 'JONOTHAN', 'SMITH', 'is the best friend ever'),
        (2, 'ROGER', 'SHU`LTS', 'is the boss!'),
        (3, 'Jeremy', 'Deimer', 'is the a good drama actor'),
        (4, 'Alexandra', 'Norusis', 'is the smart feminist');

DECLARE @ID INT;
DECLARE @xml XML;

DECLARE @BusinessCursor as CURSOR;

SET @BusinessCursor = CURSOR FOR

SELECT ID
      ,(
     SELECT t1.* 
     FOR XML PATH(''),ROOT('body'),TYPE
     )  AS TheXml
FROM @tbl AS t1

OPEN @BusinessCursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM @BusinessCursor INTO @ID, @xml;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
    --Do something with the values
    PRINT 'ID: ' +  CAST(@ID AS VARCHAR(10));
    PRINT 'XML: ' + CAST(@xml AS NVARCHAR(MAX));
    --Here you can build your BCP command.
    --Use the ID or any other information to build the file's name and save the XML out (use -w -T)

    FETCH NEXT FROM @BusinessCursor INTO @ID, @xml;
END

CLOSE @BusinessCursor;
DEALLOCATE @BusinessCursor;
```

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thx, good catch! Sometimes one thinks to complicated :-) Edited my answer...

Comment: Only thing to point out to that do produce the desired output you actually need to leave the where clause; otherwise the XML file will be defaulted to concatenate data of all the rows into every XML record. Also to avoid issues with tagging in the XML file wee need to use this   FOR XML PATH(''),ROOT('body'), TYPE

Comment: Also Shnugo, I posted my own answer based on yours. Though I excepted your answers. The problem with using WHERE t1.ID=t2.ID clause it that is casing cross apply type output. But if I omit it, it will concatenate all data from all rows into a single XML row.

Comment: @enigma6205 You are using `SELECT * FROM @tbl AS t2`. It should be enough to use `SELECT t1.* FOR XML ...` without a `FROM`.

Comment: Shnugo, what you suggested is not going to work with cursor due to this error: The FOR XML clause is not allowed in a CURSOR statement.

Comment: In my answer below in the SET BusinessCursor = CURSOR FOR I left only  SELECT * 
  FROM @tbl 
  FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('body'), TYPE. That lead to the error I mentioned above.

Comment: @enigma6205 I think you've got something wrong... See my update

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    LName, 
    FName, 
    Comments
FROM #T1
    FOR XML PATH('body');
```

I think this is your expected result:

```
<body>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <LName>JONOTHAN</LName>
  <FName>SMITH</FName>
  <Comments>is the best friend ever</Comments>
</body>
<body>
  <ID>2</ID>
  <LName>ROGER</LName>
  <FName>SHU`LTS</FName>
  <Comments>is the boss!</Comments>
</body>
<body>
  <ID>3</ID>
  <LName>Jeremy</LName>
  <FName>Deimer</FName>
  <Comments>is the a good drama actor</Comments>
</body>
<body>
  <ID>4</ID>
  <LName>Alexandra</LName>
  <FName>Norusis</FName>
  <Comments>is the smart feminist</Comments>
</body>
```

Comment: McNets, thanks for you response. But I need to do it dynamically. As I'm producing thousands of XML files as my output contains many rows of data. So I cannot hardcore it manually

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE 
(
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    LName NVARCHAR(30) NULL,
    FName NVARCHAR(30) NULL,
    Comments NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL
);

INSERT INTO @tbl (ID, LName, FName, Comments)
    VALUES
        (1, 'JONOTHAN', 'SMITH', 'is the best friend ever'),
        (2, 'ROGER', 'SHU`LTS', 'is the boss!'),
        (3, 'Jeremy', 'Deimer', 'is the a good drama actor'),
        (4, 'Alexandra', 'Norusis', 'is the smart feminist');


DECLARE @xml XML

DECLARE @BusinessCursor as CURSOR;

SET @BusinessCursor = CURSOR FOR

SELECT
-- ID
   --  ,
   (
     SELECT * 
     FROM @tbl AS t2 
--   WHERE t1.ID=t2.ID 
     FOR XML PATH(''),ROOT('body'),TYPE
     ) AS TheRowAsXml
FROM @tbl AS t1

OPEN @BusinessCursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM @BusinessCursor INTO @xml;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 

BEGIN
  SELECT ( 
     SELECT *
     FROM @tbl AS t2 
     WHERE t1.ID=t2.ID 
     FOR XML PATH(''),ROOT('body'), TYPE
     ) AS TheRowAsXml
FROM @tbl AS t1
FETCH NEXT FROM @BusinessCursor INTO @xml;
END

CLOSE @BusinessCursor;
DEALLOCATE @BusinessCursor;
```

Comment: I must admit, that I have no idea, what your `CURSOR` tries to achieve... The `SELECT` should not be repeated there I assume...

Comment: There is  select statement. It produced multiple rows in the result set. I need to generate a single XML file per single row from the resultset. And the second part to it is to save each such generated XML file separately with its own unique name. So my answer (with your help) does it well. But the issue it that it produces duplicated, "cross apply" like results. And the suggested solutions proposed by dot help.

Comment: Please see my comment to your answer above.